# Multiple ion-slides in loop not providing correct index on slides

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, swiper.js, ionic5, ion-slides

In my Ionic 5 app I have to display my custom component horizontally by ion-slides and repet each slider vertically in loop.

Following in the code.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of mainList; let i = index;">
  <ion-slides pager="true" loop="true" [options]="slideOpts" (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged(i)" #slides>
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let id of item.subList; let j = index;">
        <app-cust-comp [input]="j"></app-cust-comp>
      </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
</ng-container>
```

Following method for getting the active slide number

```
      @ViewChild('slides') slides: IonSlides;

      async slideChanged(i: number){
        const activeSlideNumber = await this.slides.getActiveIndex();
        console.log(i+' '+slideNumber);
      }
```

My goal is get the correct **active slide number for each index**. The sliders are working perfectly and the value of `activeSlideNumber` is correct every time for only the first (index 0) slider. For all sliders except first one the value of `activeSlideNumber` is always the last value change by first (index 0) slider. So if I slide the first (index 0) slider 3 times and the `activeSlideNumber` for index 0 is 2. It will always come as 2 for all other slider.

Comment: Can you try with dynamic id in inner slide element ?  [attr.id]

Comment: @SuatKarabacak, sorry, I didn't understand your solution approach. Could you please explain a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have multiple instances of an `ion-slider` in your view but `ViewChild` is used to get only one instance of the slider.

You should use `ViewChildren` instead:

`@ViewChildren(IonSlides) slides: QueryList<IonSlides>;`

Please take a look at this [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-question-64306575?file=src/app/home/home.page.ts).

[image: Demo gif]

### Component:

```
import { Component, QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss']
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChildren(IonSlides) slides: QueryList<IonSlides>; // <-- here!

  // Some fake data...
  public items = [
    {
      itemId: '1',
      subOptions: ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3']
    },
    {
      itemId: '2',
      subOptions: ['Option 4', 'Option 5', 'Option 6']
    },
    {
      itemId: '3',
      subOptions: ['Option 7', 'Option 8', 'Option 9']
    }
  ]

  constructor() {}

  public async slideChanged(i: number){
    console.log(`Slider ${i} changed`);

    // Iterate over the list of sliders to get all the selected indexes
    this.slides.toArray().forEach(async (slider, index) => {
      console.log(`Slider ${index} selected index: ${await slider.getActiveIndex()}`);
    })
  }

}
```

### View:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Home
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <ion-slides pager="true" loop="true" (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged(i)">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let id of item.subOptions; let j = index;">
          <p>(i: {{ i }} j: {{  j}}) {{ id }}</p>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
  </ng-container>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: This is really helpful!! Thank you so much @sebaferreras